# App crash at first start after downloaded from Google play (ExceptionInInitializerError)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

```
RN 0.55.4
Gradle: 2.2.3
```

There is one issue on Android. We updated some node_modules and react native to version 0.55 and everything looks ok but when we release this new version into google beta and then we download it for testing the app always crash at first run. And we run it once again and everything is ok app works fine. And we have no idea whats wrong
Errors what we get from fabric.io and its happen only once when we download that app from play.

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at tv.dailyme.android.util.ServerConfig.getUrlRegisterWithoutPhonenr(Unknown Source)
       at tv.dailyme.android.util.UserRegistration.setInstallReferrer(Unknown Source)
       at tv.dailyme.android.core.receiver.InstallReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3102)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1598)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

and this happened too at same time

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver tv.dailyme.android.core.receiver.Autostart: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3116)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1598)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

I think there is something wrong in our gradle settings

```
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

// NOTE LSA: if you change this value, You will have to change same value in "Project: Awe" => build.gradle
def googlePlayServiceVersion  = '11.0.4'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.awesome.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1007138
        versionName "6.6.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id: "7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDDc",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "9999999999"]
    }
    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "false"]
        }

        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "true"]
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-social-share')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-blur')
    compile project(':react-native-admob')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-cookies')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    // TODO LSA when we upgrade RN to 0.56 and gradle 3 we will have to remove all FORCE = TRUE and update com.android.support libs
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0"
    compile("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4") { force = true }

    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')

    compile 'tv.nexx:nexxplay-android:3.2.1'

    compile(name: 'library-release', ext: 'aar')

    compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    }

    compile project(":react-native-device-info")
    compile fileTree(dir: "node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile 'org.apache.mina:mina-statemachine:2.0.9'

    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${googlePlayServiceVersion}") {
        force = true;
    }

    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${googlePlayServiceVersion}") {
        force = true;
    }

    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${googlePlayServiceVersion}") {
        force = true;
    }

    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${googlePlayServiceVersion}") {
        force = true;
    }

    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${googlePlayServiceVersion}") {
        force = true;
    }

    compile(name: 'infonlinelib_1.1.5.1', ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: 'IRSurveyLib-1.4.0', ext:'aar')

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile group: 'com.alibaba', name: 'fastjson', version: '1.1.25'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile 'com.alibaba:fastjson:1.1.25'
    compile 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.7.0'
    compile 'ad.nugg.android:sdk:3.2.2'
}
```

Our ProGuard rules for app

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.3/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Disabling obfuscation is useful if you collect stack traces from production crashes
# (unless you are using a system that supports de-obfuscate the stack traces).
-dontobfuscate

# React Native

# Keep our interfaces so they can be used by other ProGuard rules.
# See http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/466/
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters
-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip

# Do not strip any method/class that is annotated with @DoNotStrip
-keep @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip class *
-keep @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip class *
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.DoNotStrip *;
    @com.facebook.common.internal.DoNotStrip *;
}

-keepclassmembers @com.facebook.proguard.annotations.KeepGettersAndSetters class * {
  void set*(***);
  *** get*();
}

-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule { *; }
-keep class * extends com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule { *; }
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class * { native <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIProp <fields>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp <methods>; }
-keepclassmembers class *  { @com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup <methods>; }

-dontwarn com.facebook.react.**

# TextLayoutBuilder uses a non-public Android constructor within StaticLayout.
# See libs/proxy/src/main/java/com/facebook/fbui/textlayoutbuilder/proxy for details.
-dontwarn android.text.StaticLayout

# okhttp

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**

# okio

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**


#GAID
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
  protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
  public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
  @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontwarn InnerClasses
-dontoptimize
-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver tv.dailyme.android.core.receiver.Autostart: java.lang.**NullPointerException**:
>
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.**openOrCreateDatabase**(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)'
>
> on a null object reference

it appears, as if your ProGuard configuration might not suffice **not to** obfuscate something.

you could add a `!= null` check into class `tv.dailyme.android.core.receiver.Autostart`, in order to at least not produce throw that `NPE`. improving the ProGuard `-keep` rules seems required.

Comment: I am a little bit desperate :(

Comment: @LukášŠálek it reads `-dontobfuscate` therefore this might not be the reason, however... the `Context` is `NULL` within `.receiver.Autostart`. in order to tackle this, you would have to make the `release` build  debug-able and set a breakpoint within that receiver, in order to see why the `Context` is `NULL`. `getApplicationContext()` often works, where `getContext()` fails.